# Router (WNR3500Lv2) telnet forwarding does not work for Lazy bone relay(Wifi bee/ WiFly)

Tags: port-forwarding, telnet

I have been trying to set up port forwarding for [a lazybone wifi device](http://www.tinyosshop.com/index.php?route=information/news&news_id=8)

Connecting to it from Lan works, but trying to access it from the outside just gives:

```
[B]Trying 84.208.XX4.173...[/B]
```

And nothing more happens. On the LAN I get:

```
[B]telnet 10.0.0.69 2000
Trying 10.0.0.69...
Connected to 10.0.0.69.
Escape character is '^]'.[/B]
```

I have set up:
Port Forwarding:
DoorOpener outside port:6969 inside port:2000 ip:10.0.0.69

Wireshark tells me that the lazy bone device starts pushing out ARP requests for ip: 1.2.3.4 as soon at it receives a initiating packet from the outside:

[image]

Comment: In the router log i see that the port is forwarded from 6969 to 2000. But somehow it seems the response is lost...

Comment: Are you trying to use the outside IP from inside your LAN, or did you actually try it from an outside network?

Comment: I tried using it from outside ie. via 4G. and also tried through a dynDns service...

Answer (score 0):

set ip dhcp 1 
set sys printlvl 0 
save

Setting these settings allow me to get responses from the device on the dynDns address. I figured the device was probably sending broadcasts asking for 1.2.3.4 since this is a default address in it's [setup](http://www.tinyosshop.com/datasheet/LazyBone%20IP%20config.pdf) and the setup of static IP was incomplete in some way.

Therefore I enabled DHCP as described in the [wiFly manual](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Wireless/WiFi/WiFly-RN-UM.pdf), and behold it seems to work...